# Android alternative to start Intent after sleep-Method

Tags: android, json, multithreading, android-intent

ive been searching all over the Internet, to solve this Problem on my Application, but nothing really seemed to work for me.

I have a starting Page, which handles the download of my Json-Data, and after 3 seconds, an Intent starts and redirects me to the App. This is working fine, if i have faster Internet connection. An Exception will be thrown, if the Internet connection is to slow to load all data within 3 seconds.

So my Question here is, how to get the real time for the downloading-process?

Should i handle this, with 2 Threads?

Thanks! =)

Code follows:

```
public class StartLogoPage extends Activity {

boolean haveConnectedWifi = false;
boolean haveConnectedMobile = false;
private Thread timer;
private Thread intentThread;
private Thread timerNoInternet;
private boolean serverResponse = false;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_startlogopage);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    // startIntent();
    haveNetworkConnection();
    Dashboard ds = new Dashboard();

    if (haveConnectedWifi == true || haveConnectedMobile == true) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Loading data from Internet",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        timer = new Thread() {
            public void run() {

                try {
                    System.out.println("timer Thread started.");
                    // start timer
                    UrlHandler urlHandler = new UrlHandler();
                    urlHandler.handleEvents(1);
                    urlHandler.handleNews(1);
                    urlHandler.handlePerson(1);
                    urlHandler.handleWebIndex(1);
                    urlHandler.handleNavigation(1);

                    sleep(3000);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {

                    Intent openDashboard = new Intent(
                            "com.example.incomingandroid.DASHBOARD");
                    System.out.println("openDashboard" + openDashboard);
                    // openDashboard.clone();
                    // if (openDashboard != null)
                    startActivity(openDashboard);

                }

            }

        };
        timer.start();



    } else {

        Toast.makeText(
                this,
                "No Internet Connection was found. This Application needs Internet to be started.",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        timerNoInternet = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sleep(6000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    finish();
                }
            }
        };
        timerNoInternet.start();
    }

}

private boolean haveNetworkConnection() {

    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
    for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) {
        if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
            if (ni.isConnected())
                haveConnectedWifi = true;

        if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
            if (ni.isConnected())
                haveConnectedMobile = true;

    }
    return haveConnectedWifi || haveConnectedMobile;
}
```

Comment: can u specificate your answer please ? =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `Handler`

```
 Handler h = new Handler();

    Runnable r = new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    };
    h.postDelayed(r, 30000);//delay 3 seconds
```

If you want to something after a delay of 3 seconds you can use `Handler`.

Edit:

You could use a `AsyncTask` do your downloading there and then in onPostExecute start the activity. `onPostExecute` is executed after `doInbackground` computation finishes.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i need a Solution that doesnt delay the time for a manually setted time (like here 3 seconds) . I need to wait, as long as the JSON-data has been loaded.

Comment: @charly_freak35 use Asynctask

Comment: I did that already, its working great, its only the startingPage of my Application. I need to get the download-time, and wait for exact that time. And after that the Intent should be started =)

Comment: @charly_freak35 when downlaoding finished you start the activity. do downloading in doInbackground. then after downloading in onpostExecute start activity :). you can also display the progress percentage downloaded. and i did that already. why not post your implementation of asynctask and let us see what's wrong

Comment: That would be working, but i forget to mention that my Async Task class downloads 5 different JSON-ressources. Thats why I implemented that Thread with the sleep method =) Is there an Alternative?

Comment: @charly_freak35 first post what you have done and then specify what is the problem and then specify what is needed. Your comments and the code in the post is confusing. "Async Task class downloads 5 different JSON-ressources". So what is the problem?

Comment: @charly_freak35 and you can use a executor if you need parallel execution.

Comment: okay sorry. I will try to explain it correctly. So my StartLogoPage-Class starts the Async Task Class, five times one after the other. The Async - Task class simply downloads all Json-Ressources and provides to each class the information. (This happens at the beginning in the background). After this Procedure, the Application with all Information will be shown. The main Problem that i have now is, that i manually setted the sleep-timer (3-seconds-delay). If the Internet connection is fast at this place it will be loaded, and everything will be shown. But in other case, the App crashes.

Comment: Like you see i need something other than this sleep(3000). I need here the real time to wait until every 5 JSON-Objects has been downloaded, wherever the Intenet connection is.

Comment: @charly_freak35 you do not have control over the internet speed and the time taken may differ. If you truly want parallel execution, you can invoke executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor, Object[]) with THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR. Now starting activity can be done in onPostExecute sine only after doInbackground finishes work it is executed. now what is the problem using asynctask. You cannot get real time.

Comment: Yeah okay i got that, but if i implement that Intent in the onPostExecute-Method - shouldn't it be called 5 times in a row?

Comment: @charly_freak35 nope. no need for that. use `new TheTask()executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, "url1","url2","url3"...);` . in onpostexecute start activity. pls read asynctask docs. any furthere queries post a new post